# Free groups : Isomorphism beetween the free group $F_{X}$ and a group $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

The Question : Let $F$ be a group and let $j : X \rightarrow F $ be a mapping.

Assume that for every
mapping $f$ of $X$ into a group $G$, there is a homomorphism $\phi$ of F into G unique such that
$f = ϕ ◦ j$ . Show that $F_{X} \simeq F $.

My Attempt : I used the universal property : Let $η : X \rightarrow F_{X}$ be the canonical injection. For every mapping
$f$ of $X$ into a group $G$, there is a homomorphism $ϕ'$ of $F_{X}$ into $G$ unique such
that $f = ϕ' ◦ η$, namely
$ϕ' (a_{1}, a_{2}, . . ., a_{n}) = f (a_{1}) f (a_{2}) · · · f (a_{n})$.

I searched a homomorphism , I found this one $\zeta : F_{X} \rightarrow F$ such that $\zeta(())=0_{F} $ (The image of the empty word) and $  \zeta(a_{1}, a_{2}, . . ., a_{n}) =  j(a_{1}) j (a_{2}) · · · j (a_{n}) $ .  I couldn't find the kernel of this homomorphism. if $Ker \zeta=\{0\}$ then  $F_{X} \simeq F $. Otherwise finding another homomorphism will be a key to solve this problem.

Thank you for reading my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about the universal property of $F_X$, then you know that you can define a *unique* homomorphism $\phi\colon F_X\to F$ such that, for every $x\in X$,
$$
\phi(x)=j(x)
$$
On the other hand, the property of $F$ allows to build a unique homomorphism $\psi\colon F\to F_X$ such that $\eta=\psi\circ j$.

Now, for $x\in X$,
$$
\psi\circ\phi(x)=\psi(\phi(x))=\psi(j(x))=\psi\circ j(x)=\eta(x)
$$
Hence, by uniqueness, $\psi\circ\phi$ is the identity on $F_X$.

Similarly,
$$
\phi\circ\psi(j(x))=\phi(\eta(x))=\phi(x)=j(x)
$$
By uniqueness, $\phi\circ\psi$ must be the identity on $F$.

Comment: Question 1 : Why did you consider that $X \subset F_{X}$ ?

Comment: @BriedjYacine If you don't want that, use $\eta$, but it's not restrictive to assume $X\subset F_X$.

Comment: Can you please explain to me the part of $ϕ∘ψ$ must be the identity on $F$. For the first part $ψ∘ϕ$ is the identity on $F_{X}$ because $\eta (X)$ generates $F_{X}$ . but in the second case how we can say for sure that every element $y$ in $F$ can be written  $y= ϕ∘ψ(x) $ for some $x$. $j(x)$ is injective not surjective. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @BriedjYacine The identity map $\iota\colon F\to F$ satisfies $\iota\circ j=j$; so any homomorphism $\alpha\colon F\to F$ satisfying $\alpha\circ j=j$ must be equal to the identity.